# Photocopies of R' Moshe's tefillin

Tags: internet, tefilin, moshe-feinstein

The answers to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8232/did-rabbi-dovid-feinstein-of-uzda-wear-tefilin-that-were-ktav-ari-or-ktav-beit-y) discuss photocopies of the R"T tefillin used by R' Moshe Feinstein. Are scans of these photocopies available on the internet?

Comment: There are people from the Lower East Side who claim that Reb Moshe never actually wore the R'T tephilin mentioned in his tshuvos.

Comment: @user6591 The ones the Lubavitcher Rebbe had written for him and hand delivered?

Comment: @Double The Rebbe himself wrote them, or His personal soffer? But either way, yes. I forgot the details of the story but supposedly something happened that stopped him from wearing them and he took it as a sign not to wear them at all. Who knows what the truth is.

Comment: @user6591, most hold that R"T's tefillin should be put on in private, due to concerns of yuhoroh

Comment: @Noach I'm not sure what that has to do with what I wrote. If you mean to imply that he put them on when nobody was looking, that wasn't the story.

Comment: @user6591, from what I know of R' Moshe Feinstein, it's unlikely that he wouldn't have put on R"T's

Comment: @Noach I don't know what you know about him and I don't know what else you would guess about him based on those presumptions, but apparently people who actually lived near him and are making an actual claim about an event disagree with your assumption.